# android custom dialog with multiple image buttons

Tags: android, android-intent, dialog, android-alertdialog, imagebutton

I am trying to implement a share action that on user's choice, he gets a popup dialog with specific share actions (over specific distinct apps - desired screen:[desired layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nbloj.jpg)).

I would like to have 6 ImageButtons.

Till now, I could get the popup window (but the onclick listenes - were like dead) or (on the other hand) the app would crash.

My Layout for the popup is:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/colorAccent">


    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/viber"
        android:id="@+id/viber_share_button"
        android:layout_below="@+id/twitter_share_button"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/twitter_share_button"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/facebook_share_button" />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/twitter"
        android:id="@+id/twitter_share_button"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/facebook_messenger"
        android:id="@+id/messanger_share_button"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/viber_share_button"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/facebook_share_button" />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/instagram"
        android:id="@+id/instagram_share_button"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/twitter_share_button"
        android:layout_marginStart="31dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/whatsapp"
        android:id="@+id/whatsapp_share_button"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/viber_share_button"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/instagram_share_button"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/viber_share_button"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/instagram_share_button" />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/facebook"
        android:id="@+id/facebook_share_button"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/twitter_share_button"
        android:layout_marginEnd="39dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

the code that I use is:

```
private void displayIntentOptions(final Bitmap bitmap){



        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
        View promptView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.share_buttons, null);
        final AlertDialog alertD = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();
        alertD.setView(promptView);
        alertD.show();
        ImageButton facebook_button = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.facebook_share_button);
        ImageButton twitter_button = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.twitter_share_button);
        ImageButton intagram_button = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.instagram_share_button);
        ImageButton messanger_button = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.messanger_share_button);
        ImageButton viber_button = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.viber_share_button);
        ImageButton whatsapp_button = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.whatsapp_share_button);

        facebook_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

            }
        });
        twitter_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                shareTwitter(v, bitmap);//just a sample of what I want to do
            }
        });
        intagram_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

            }
        });
        messanger_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

            }
        });
        viber_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

            }
        });
        whatsapp_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

            }
        });
    }
```

This code doesn't work at all. I would be thankful, If someone could help me with this. Since on a regular dialog I cannot have all those ImageButtons, I tried to make a custom one. 
Furthermore, I would like to know if this is a good practice, or I should implement a new Intent for this.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change one little thing

Was

```
final AlertDialog alertD = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();
alertD.setView(promptView);
alertD.show();
```

Now

```
  final AlertDialog.Builder alertD = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
  alertD.setView(promptView);
  alertD.show();
```

### Update

Also there is a problem in this

```
ImageButton facebook_button = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.facebook_share_button);
```

It will be null, because you'r looking at Activity(or fragments) views, but not in AlertDialog ones. You need to set it like this

```
ImageButton facebook_button = (ImageButton)promptView.findViewById(R.id.facebook_share_button);
```

Comment: Thanks, but just tried it and it doesn't work. It instantly terminates current activity.

Comment: @SpyrosSou I just pasted all code into test app and it works OK. But I don't have drawables. Are you sure, that all is OK with them? Also This code won't work <17 API (look at layout warnings)

Comment: Thanks for your confirmation, but the issue isn't the drawables, as I can have them displayed on popup window (with another implementation, but with dead onClickListeners).
I believe that the problem has to do with the java code.

Comment: thanks. seems to work (I have to modify the share action to be sure).

Comment: @SpyrosSou you have to modify all other buttons that have this error